# Android Activity back manager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my android activity I have 3 activity A B C 
But when i start A - >B - >C - >A  and when i click back all activity remain A-C-B-A

I want when I press back in current activity it returns to activity A

Help

Comment: Are you overriding `onBackPressed()`? The default behaviour does exactly what you want, you must be doing something strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want an Activity to not be added to the back stack after leaving it just call:

```
finish();
```

So for example, to start Activity B from Activity A and get rid of Activity A completely:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
finish();
```

Now if you press the back button in Activity B, it will exit the app because there are no other Activities in the back stack.

For your specific situation, you can call finish on everything except Activity A, which will make Activity A the only Activity in your back stack. So the back button will always send you back to Activity A no matter what Activity you press it from.